# Two GPU's - one for rendering the game, and one for driving the display

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu

Ok so in my computer I have two GPU's. One of them is the higher performance AMD GPU (which I want to use to render games) and the other is an old low-end NVIDIA GPU which I use to run my monitor (Apple Cinema Display).

Is it possible to run the monitor from the old gpu with the right connectivity, and then do all of the graphics rendering on the card which won't be running any displays?

Comment: What is wrong with connecting your display to the AMD GPU? Does it lack the right connection for the monitor?

Comment: @Mokubai yeah it needs display port or mini display port. it only has vga, dvi and hdmi...

Comment: HDMI -> Mini Display Port/Display Port are pretty common and cheap.

Comment: Your BIOS may allow you to set the NVIDIA as the default.  You won't get crossfire or SLI, but the software will determine which it uses.  If the software does not allow a choice you are at its mercy.

Comment: @heavyd really? couldn't find any...